# Как сохранить переменные анонимного типа в к коллекцию?

Tags: c#

Как сохранить переменные анонимного типа в к коллекцию?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Зависит от того, что дальше предполагается делать с коллекцией.

Если коллекция - объект временный, то можно вынести работу с ней в обобщенный метод (разумеется, сама коллекция также будет иметь снаружи анонимный тип):

```
static List<T> CreateCollection<T>(T item) {
    return new List<T> { item };
}

static void AddToCollection<T>(List<T> list, T item) {
    list.Add(item);
}

// ...

var c = CreateCollection(new { a = 5, b = "foo" });
AddToCollection(c, new { a = 6, b = "bar" });
```

Если коллекцию надо куда-то сохранить, можно попробовать найти базовый тип или написать обобщенный адаптер:

```
ICollection Collection { get; set; }
IEnumerable<object> AnotherCollection { get; set; }

// ...

Collection = CreateCollection(new { a = 5, b = "foo" });
AnotherCollection = CreateCollection(new { a = 6, b = "bar" });
```

Также всегда можно воспользоваться "тяжелой артиллерией" - `dynamic` (но будет тормозить, я предупредил).

Но если с анонимными классами слишком много проблем - возможно, стоит уже перейти к обычному классу?

Comment: Если коллекция уже есть, то по идее `AddToCollection` на нужен?

Comment: @VladD, ага, получается так, кстати в примере создания коллекции, у нее сразу элемент будет, то есть таким образом нельзя создать пустую коллекцию

Comment: @Grundy при наличии *шаблона элемента* - можно

Comment: @PavelMayorov, я имел ввиду в конкретном примере в ответе. ты всегда в список вставляешь элемент который передали

Comment: @Grundy ну так я описал принцип, а не решение

Answer (score 7):

Альтернативный вариант создания списка без использования generic метода:

```
var collection = Enumerable.Range(0, 0)
                           .Select(a => new { a = default(int), b = default(string) })
                           .ToList();
collection.Add(new { a = 5, b = "foo" });
```

В данном случае используется [Enumerable.Range](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.linq.enumerable.range(v=vs.110).aspx), который возвращает пустую коллекцию, но за счет селекта определяется тип элементов. При применении `ToList` получается обычный список с типом элементов анонимного класса.

Comment: Ну я бы не сказал, что без Generic метода. Всё же `Select` и `ToList` очень даже Generic.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov, я имел ввиду своего собственного, как в примере Павла, в котором только вызывается конструктор List, с нужным generic параметром

Answer (score 2):

Допустим есть переменная `item`:

```
var item = new { Value = 1, Text = "abc" };
```

### Первый способ

Можно сделать из неё массив

```
var items = new[] { item };
```

Таким же способом можно сделать из нескольких переменных массив.
Разумеется, его можно превратить в список с помощью метода `ToList()`.

### Второй способ

Можно просто использовать метод `Enumerable.Repeat`

```
var items = Enumerable.Repeat(item, 1);
```

Если надо продублировать этот элемент несколько раз, то передаём в этот метод не `1`, а нужное количество раз. Затем добавляем вызов `ToList` или `ToArray` по вкусу.

### Третий способ

Идея подана @Grundy, но я бы уточнил, что вовсе необязательно вызывать `Select` именно для последовательности чисел полученной из метода `Enumerable.Range`.

Берите любую **подходящую** коллекцию и вызывайте метод `Select`. Если также вам нужен индекс помните о перегрузке [`Select` с индексом](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534869(v=vs.110).aspx). И вообще используйте этот способ, когда первый и второй не так удобно использовать иначе он будет выглядеть искусственно. Пример:

```
var strings = new[] { "abc", "def" };

// [ "{ Value = 1, Text = "abc" }, { Value = 2, Text = "def" } ]
var items = strings.Select((value, index) => new { Value = index + 1, Text = value }).ToArray();
```

### Добавление элементов после инициализации

Потом (если нужно) можно добавлять элементы либо через метод `Add` списка (класс `List`), либо через `LINQ` метод `Concat` (немного извращённо, но тоже можно).

```
items = items.Concat(new[] { new { Value = 2, Text = "def" } }).ToArray();
```

Comment: обрати внимание, что мой код создает пустую последовательность и Select нужен только для указания типа элементов

Comment: @Grundy Да я это заметил. Просто если его читать буквально или просто он будет первым ответом, то это будет выглядеть странно по этой причине.